# The requested resource is not available- 404 - RESTful web service in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, rest, tomcat

I've been using the following guide to develop a hello world REST web service.
The guide can be found at: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Creating_a_JAX-RS_Web_Service
I'm trying to open the path:  "http://localhost:8080/BeezerServer/jaxrs/addresses"

but it keeps on saying that "The requested resource (/BeezerServer/jaxrs/addresses) is not available."

my web.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-    app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
  <display-name>BeezerServer</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <description>JAX-RS Tools Generated - Do not modify</description>
    <servlet-name>JAX-RS Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.wink.server.internal.servlet.RestServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>com.test.AddressBookApplication</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>JAX-RS Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/jaxrs/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

The project looks as following(in case it might help someone):
[image]

The tomcat log:

```
Aug 31, 2012 7:48:58 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program...
Aug 31, 2012 7:48:59 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Aug 31, 2012 7:48:59 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Aug 31, 2012 7:48:59 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1536 ms
Aug 31, 2012 7:48:59 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Aug 31, 2012 7:48:59 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.29
Aug 31, 2012 7:48:59 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Aug 31, 2012 7:48:59 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Aug 31, 2012 7:48:59 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 737 ms
```

AddressBookApplication.java:

```
package com.test;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

public class AddressBookApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
        classes.add(AddressBook.class);
        return classes;
    }

}
```

AddressBook.java:

```
    package com.test;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;

/**
 * A sample resource that provides access to 
 * server configuration properties
 */
@Path(value="/addresses")
public class AddressBook {
    public AddressBook() {
        System.out.println();
    }
    private static String[] list = new String[] {
        "Eric- 932 Deloraine Av.",
        "Yen - 687 Markham Rd.",
        "Keith - 4301 McCowan Rd.",
        "Ron - 465 Melrose St.",
        "Jane - 35 Cranbrooke Av.",
        "Sam - 146 Brooke Av."

};

@GET
@Produces(value="text/plain")
public String getList() {
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    buffer.append("{");
    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; ++i) {
        if (i != 0) 
            buffer.append(", ");
        buffer.append(list[i]);
    }
    buffer.append("}");

    return buffer.toString();
}

@GET
@Produces(value="text/plain")
@Path(value="{id}")
public String getPropety(@PathParam("id") int id) {
    if (id > -1 && id < list.length -1) {
        return list[id];
    }
    else {
        return "Name Not Found";
    }
}

@GET
@Produces(value="text/html")
@Path(value="html")
public String getHTMLList()
{
    return "<html><body><p><b>Hello</b></body></html>";
}

@POST
@Produces(value="text/html")
@Path(value="form")
public String handlePost(@PathParam("name") String name,@PathParam("age") int age)
{
    return "<html><body><p>name: " + name + "<p>age: " + age;
}

}
```

Comment: 404 means your REST service is not deployed properly. Can you add the server log details if you see any exceptions there ?

Comment: You mean the one from the eclipse console?

Comment: I mean from the place where your server is started. So, if it is Eclipse then Yes. Also, Please add your AddressBookApplication. I have removed the image from the question which is not visible.